# 英語が残っている: 行動履歴 pending edit on ... tag wiki

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

まだTransifexに参加できていないのでここに言うのですが、行動履歴の

```
pending edit on (タグの名前) tag wiki
pending edit on (タグの名前) tag wiki excerpt
```

が英語です。
**案**

> {タグの名前}の説明の編集(保留中)
>     {タグの名前}の抜粋の編集(保留中)

のように横にステータスを表示する形です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その表記は [`[pending edit]($reviewUrl$) on $postLink$`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40290028?key=8a7ea93bbbc6a07929176cc1fa54be8e) という形で登録されていて、通常の質問・回答に編集提案を出した時にも使われる文章です。質問のタイトルには結構長い物もありますから、タイトルは後ろに置いた方が見やすいように思います。例えば・・・

> [保留中](//)の編集： [タグwikiの編集、抜粋が英語](//)
>   [保留中](//)の編集： [タグ debian の説明](//)
>   [承認された](//)編集： [タグ debian の抜粋](//)

ただ、`tag wiki excerpt` というフレーズはTransifex上だと全て翻訳済みになっているので、ちょっとjmacさんに相談してみます。

Comment: そのような形なら、それのほうが分かりやすいですね。

Comment: ひとまず `pending edit on ...` に関してはTransifexで翻訳しました。

Comment: 分かりました。(タグの例がdebianなのはたまたまなのかそうではないのか…)